# Call similar to $.get in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.get(url, {}, checkResponse)
```

And the following function:

```
function checkResponse(content) {}
```

The parameter "content" here is the result of the "get". I wanted to implement `$.ajax` to able to wait for the process to complete before it jump to the next chunk of code. I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.toString());
        checkResponse(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Here's what happened, the alert for the `data.toString()` gives empty string value while it should give me the url page content, and after it hits the alert it jumps to the error section and displays the alert "error".

Comment: u need to specify the data type you are expecting like; json,html. use `contentType` for that purpose and also some more code on what is being called and returned will help to solve your problem. Some Help here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You need to specify the dataType only if you have a poorly written server side script which doesn't set the proper Content-Type. If your server side script sets the correct Content-Type, jQuery is able to automatically infer it and parse the response accordingly.

Comment: As a side note, why do you think you need to use `$.ajax` to be *able to wait for the process to complete*?

Comment: @m90, because he doesn't want to use AJAX anymore. He wants to set the `async` parameter to `false` and completely kill the user experience by freezing the browser and the whole point of AJAX. With `$.get` it is not possible to set the `async` parameter to `false`. `$.get` is always asynchronous - the way AJAX was meant to be.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov that's true :P

Comment: could you use a tool like Fiddler and post the HTTP response?

Comment: Holy crap: `$.ajax({async: false, type: 'GET', url: url}).done(checkResponse);` Be aware that some requests, like jsonp, can only be asynchronous, and that this approach is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for responses guys, i tried adding a "dataType:html" but it didn't work. as for the contentType i don't think there is a need for me to alter the default since i am expecting a plain text. All i want is to send a url and get the html plain text as the result.

Comment: I read while i was searching that you can't get any result from the GET unless the link was on your Domain or SubDomain only, otherwise it considered a cross-domain-scripting. If that was the case then that is what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @user733659, cross domain AJAX calls are not allowed. Possible workarounds include JSONP or CORS but the remote server that you are trying to send the request to needs to support it. Is this the case? If it isn't then your only option is to write a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge and then send the AJAX request to your script.

Comment: In the case you mentioned it's true, but i am developing a small applications where i check for some text inside pages, so any internet url can be passed. That is the problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case you will have to develop a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge. This script will be passed an url as parameter and the script will retrieve the contents from this remote url and return it to the response. Then simply send an AJAX request to your own script - it's the only way to make this work with any type of url over the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the discussion in the comments section you are trying to send cross domain AJAX calls to arbitrary urls on the internet. Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built into the browsers this is not possible.

Possible workarounds involve using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) but since you will be sending requests to arbitrary urls that you have no control over they might not be an option. The only *viable* solution in this case is for you to write a server side script that you will host on your domain acting as a bridge. This script will receive an url as parameter and send an HTTP request to this url in order to retrieve the result. Then it will simply return the result back to the response. Finally you will send an AJAX request to your own server side script.

Comment: I solved my issue but i don't know if it's the right thing to do, i have used the .load() method and it retrieves results with no problem at all. Is this a good solution.

Comment: `.load` still uses AJAX and is still subject to the same origin policy restriction. If the code works it's probably because you've sent a request to an url which supports CORS. It won't work with other sites that do not support it.